# Merge rows and fill empty positions with group_by and?

Tags: r, merge

very new to R coding and I've been trying to format/merge rows in a df using group_by from dplyr. However, I'm not quite there yet.

This is a simplification of my data table. The first three entries share the same id, and the last two entries share the same id.

```
ID                   Assay1  Assay2  Assay3  Assay4  Assay5
13,12 Months,<=-65C  12      NA      NA      NA      NA
13,12 Months,<=-65C  NA      11      NA      NA      NA
13,12 Months,<=-65C  NA      NA      33      NA      NA
09,06 Months,<=-65C  112     NA      NA      NA      NA
09,06 Months,<=-65C  NA      115     NA      NA      NA
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
ID                   Assay1  Assay2  Assay3  Assay4  Assay5
13,12 Months,<=-65C  12      11      33      NA      NA
09,06 Months,<=-65C  112     115     NA      NA      NA
```

So that the values in AssayValueX are merged into one row per unique id. I've used group_by with summarise but I dont want a summary... I want a new df with the merged rows! If other functions are more appropriate to achieve this, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can using `dplyr` and `zoo`

```
df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate_each(funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE)))%>%filter(row_number()==n())


ID                   Assay1  Assay2  Assay3  Assay4  Assay5
13,12 Months,<=-65C  12      11      33      NA      NA
09,06 Months,<=-65C  112     115     NA      NA      NA
```

**EDIT**

For you addtional question

Data:

```
ID Assay1 Assay2 Assay3 Assay4 Assay5
1 13,12 Months,<=-65C     12     13     NA     NA     NA
2 13,12 Months,<=-65C     11     11    999     NA     NA
3 13,12 Months,<=-65C     NA     NA     33     NA     NA
4 09,06 Months,<=-65C    112     NA     NA     NA     NA
5 09,06 Months,<=-65C     NA    115     NA     NA     NA
```

**Solution**

```
df=df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise_all(funs(toString(na.omit(.))))
df[df=='']=NA
    > df
                   ID Assay1 Assay2  Assay3 Assay4 Assay5
                <chr>  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1 09,06 Months,<=-65C    112    115    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
2 13,12 Months,<=-65C 12, 11 13, 11 999, 33   <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: I've now come across cases where two or three rows share the same ID, and all have a value for Assay1 (or Assay2, Assay3). This is because the experiment is performed with several replicates for the same condition. Can you suggest how I could aggregate/paste/paste0 the two or three values in one cell? So, the result for one row would be something: ID = 13,12 Months, <=-65C; Assay1 = 12, 13, 19; Assay2 = 11, 115, 23 etc...

Comment: @pdench see my edit, it will give back what you want

Comment: @pdench if it is what you want ,hope you can  accept my answer ~

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyr` solution. With your example data, there is no Assay4 and Assay5 data because they are `NA`s, but it should work with your real life data. Basically, the rationale is to `gather` the data, remove the NAs and `spread` it again.

```
library(tidyr)
df%>%
  gather(Assay, value,-ID)%>% 
  filter(!is.na(value))%>% 
  spread(Assay,value)

                   ID Assay1 Assay2 Assay3
1 09,06 Months,<=-65C    112    115     NA
2 13,12 Months,<=-65C     12     11     33
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="ID                   Assay1  Assay2  Assay3  Assay4  Assay5
'13,12 Months,<=-65C'  12      NA      NA      NA      NA
'13,12 Months,<=-65C'  NA      11      NA      NA      NA
'13,12 Months,<=-65C'  NA      NA      33      NA      NA
'09,06 Months,<=-65C'  112     NA      NA      NA      NA
'09,06 Months,<=-65C'  NA      115     NA      NA      NA",
 header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: kudos for the data re-generation

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution via `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%  
  summarise_all(funs(sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., . == 0, NA)))

# A tibble: 2 x 6
#                   ID Assay1 Assay2 Assay3 Assay4 Assay5
#               <fctr>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 09,06_Months,<=-65C    112    115     NA     NA     NA
#2 13,12_Months,<=-65C     12     11     33     NA     NA
```